# Given positive real numbers $a, b, c$ with $ab + bc + ca = 1.$ Prove that $ \sqrt{a^{2} + 1} + \sqrt{b^{2} + 1} + \sqrt{c^{2} + 1}\leq 2(a+b+c).$

Tags: inequality

Given positive real numbers $a, b, c$ with $ab + bc + ca = 1.$ Prove that $$ \sqrt{a^{2} + 1} + \sqrt{b^{2} + 1} + \sqrt{c^{2} + 1}\leq 2(a+b+c).$$

I have no idea to prove this inequality.

Comment: I solved your problem by another way. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\sqrt{a^2+1}= \sqrt{a^2+ab+bc+ca}=\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}\le \frac{(2a+b+c)}{2}~~\text{AM-GM}\,.$$
Addling three similar results we prove that
$$\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\le \frac{4(a+b+c)}{2}=2(a+b+c)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, square both sides:
$$\small{2\left[\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}+\sqrt{(b^2+1)(c^2+1)}+\sqrt{(c^2+1)(a^2+1)}\right]}\le \\
3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+5$$
By AM-GM:
$$2\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}\le a^2+b^2+2$$
Hence, we need to prove:
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+6\le 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+5 \Rightarrow \\
1\le a^2+b^2+c^2$$
which is true, because:
$$1=ab+bc+ca\le a^2+b^2+c^2.$$